# Byte array to string doesn't work

Tags: c#

I've tried the following but it returns a weird string:

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
```

Here's my byte array. I want to convert it to `"8.31.99.141"`.

[image]

Comment: What does not work? What kind of string so you expect?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this is a misunderstanding. A byte's value does not directly relate to a string's character representation. That is to say that the byte `8` is not necessarily `"8"` in a string. The act of converting between bytes and characters is called `Encoding`.

You can test some encoding yourself:

```
var testString = "my test string";
var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(testString);
var confirmString = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

To output the byte value directly as a string, use this:

```
var result = string.Join(".", bytes);
```

This will implicitly call `.ToString()` on the bytes, which returns the byte value as a string. **Note that this is MUCH different than encoding.**

Comment: I think he wants the numeric representation of each byte and not it's encoded value.

Comment: @Kevin - I did update my answer to reflect this as well.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
string result = String.Join(".", lol);
```

Comment: Not sure why this had a downvote: it is perfectly fine

Comment: @Crono String.Join also takes an array of Object

Comment: @Crono: Time to read the docs... can take an `IEnumerable<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: take a look at this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(".", buffer.ToList().Select(i=>i.ToString()));
```

Comment: everything after `buffer` is redundant and undesirable; the extra list, the iterator, the delegate, etc

Answer (score 0):

If your buffer length may differ:

```
var result = string.Join(".", buffer);
```

If length is always fixed to four (like for an IP adress for example), this reads better IMHO:

```
var result = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", buffer);
```

Of course this is assuming you want the string representation of each individual byte.